# Search In a Directory and Subdirectories and List All Matched Files and Folder

Tags: vb.net

I want Search In a Directory for multiple pattern ( For Example : `*.jpg,*.png,Davood,*.dj` ) that Result shoud return all **files and folders** that matched with my pattern,

can any body help to me ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Modified to search multiple pattherns

```
Dim Patterns As String() = yourPatterns.Split(","c)
Dim matchedDirectories As New List(Of String)
Dim matchedFiles As New List(Of String)
For Each pattern in Patterns
  Dim targetDirectory As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(yourDirectoryPath)
  Dim yourPatternToMatch As String = pattern
  matchedDirectories.Concat(targetDirectory.GetDirectories(yourPatternToMatch, System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).AsEnumerable.Select(Function(d) d.FullName)))
  matchedFiles.Concat(targetDirectory.GetFiles(yourPatternToMatch, System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).AsEnumerable.Select(Function(f) f.FullName))
 Next

 return matchedDirectories.Concat(matchedFiles)
```

This will return a `List(Of String)` that match `yourPatternToMatch`

Comment: It's Only Search By One Pattern and not listed directory ( only files listed with this ) Thanks

Comment: `'SELECT' in not a member of 'System.Array'`

Comment: @Davood try now I had my ToList() and Select(predicate) backwards

Comment: Thansk you `msarchet` But now give `'ToList' is not a member of 'System.Array'`